# Gremlin querying through groovy script using bulbs

Tags: python, titan, gremlin, bulbs

I'm trying to figure out a better way of querying `titan` with `gremlin` through the python library `bulbs`.

I have a simple tree

```
       n0
     /   \
   /       \
  n1       n2
 /  \       \
n3  n4      n5
```

and I want to get `n4` and the edges: `e[n0 -> n1] => e1`, `e[n1 -> n4] => e2` leading up to `n4`.  So in this example I want `[e1, e2, n4]`

I know all the indexes of the nodes before I do a query.  In this example `node_ids = ['ddbe4d52e7034ffeb17c9426fc1484af, '754d5e84daad4140ba93cb10ce00cde0', '7b2848543b444fcc94e69d7930ffa996']`

With this information I can build this query which I feel is rather long and repetitive

```
g.V('nid', 'ddbe4d52e7034ffeb17c9426fc1484af').out
    .has('nid', '754d5e84daad4140ba93cb10ce00cde0').out
    .has('nid', '7b2848543b444fcc94e69d7930ffa996')
```

This only gives me the last node.  I'm still trying to figure out this `sideAffect` thing that `gremlin` has to return the edges that I need.

I know I can create custom scripts and use those thorough `gremlin`, but I'm very new to all this stuff so help would be appreciated.

pseudo code of something I'm looking for

```
def get_node(nodes) {
    edges = []
    for node in nodes:
        get first node
        find edge that goes to second node
        edges.append(edge)
    return edges + last node
}
```

Also if anyone has a good tutorial on gremlin/groovy that would be helpful

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the path. Try:

```
g.V('nid', 'ddbe4d52e7034ffeb17c9426fc1484af').outE.inV
.has('nid', '754d5e84daad4140ba93cb10ce00cde0').outE.inV
.has('nid', '7b2848543b444fcc94e69d7930ffa996').path
```

This gives you a list with:

```
[startVertex, startIntermediateEdge, intermediateVertex, intermediateTargetEdge, targetVertex]
```